# Building the Kernel

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, kernel

When I build/compile a Kernel, I do so from /home/username/build.  Upon completion there is obviously a Kernel directory in the /home/username/build directory.  This directory is huge!  My question, is it safe to remove that directory upon successfully booting the just compiled Kernel?  Are there parts, or all of that directory that I should move to my / partition?  I've never compiled/built a Kernel using the root user account, or from the / partition.  If I should be building it as the root user, then where on the / partition should I do my build from?

Sorry, I know it's more than one question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional location for building kernels is `/usr/src/linux-{version}`, with a symlink from there to `/usr/src/linux` for the benefit of source code that looks for Linux kernel header files. Other locations (such as your own home directory) should work, though. I haven't checked recently to see if there's some newer location that's become the standard since I learned it many moons ago.

Yes, the kernel files, and compiled kernels, consume lots of space. Unless you're working on a very space-constrained medium (like a tablet or netbook with a tiny MMC "disk"), I recommend you keep the compiled kernel around -- at least for a while. I often find that a locally-compiled kernel may seem to work well, but then I encounter a problem -- a missing driver or a need to tweak a compile-time option that I overlooked. In such cases, it's often much faster and easier to adjust one setting and recompile (which may involve just compiling one or two files rather than the whole kernel, depending on what needs adjusting) than to start over from scratch.

An intermediate alternative to deleting the entire directory tree is to do a `make clean` in the kernel directory. This should remove all the object (`*.o`) files while preserving the source code and your unique kernel configuration. You'll still end up using disk space, but not nearly as much as the compiled kernel consumes.

As to the account used, I use my normal user account to compile the kernel; but it's necessary to be `root` (or use `sudo`) to copy the kernel file to `/boot`, to copy the modules to `/lib/modules` (via `make modules_install`), and to create an initial RAM disk (via commands that vary from one distribution to another). There are lots of alternative ways to compile and install a kernel, though, some of which have other needs. Also, to write to `/usr/src`, you must be `root` on most distributions. If you compile as a normal user, this will require adjusting permissions, either on `/usr/src` as a whole or on the Linux kernel tree *after* you extract it as `root`. (Or I suppose you could extract it elsewhere as a normal user and then move it to `/usr/src` as `root`.) Either approach has security implications, particularly on a multi-user system.